# Lambda function with different signatures from std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I don't understand why the third case is ok (even if the lambda's arguments type is different from the `std::function` type are) while the compiler complains with the fourth one:

```
function<int(int)> idInt = [](int i) {return i;}; //OK
function<int(int&)> idInt = [](int &i) {return i;}; //OK
function<int(int&)> idInt = [](int i) {return i;}; //OK
function<int(int)> idInt = [](int &i) {return i;}; //ERROR!
```

Comment: Because there exists a conversion from lvalue to rvalue (the so-called "lvalue-to-rvalue conversion"), but there is no conversion from rvalue to lvalue. The constructors of `std::function` don't care about declared signatures, only about whether the implied *call expression* is valid.

Comment: Why not using `auto`? `auto idInt = ...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you write:

```
function<int(int)> idInt = [](int &i) {return i;}; //ERROR!
```

then you say that `idInt` can wrap a function,closure,.. which can be called with `int` argument. But this is not true in case of `[](int &i) {return i;};`, because you cannot call it with integral literal like here:

```
auto fn = [](int &i) {return i;};
fn(1); // error - you try to bind temporary to reference
```

you can fix it by changing signature to use rvalue reference or const&:

```
std::function<int(int)> idInt1 = []( int &&i) {return i;};
std::function<int(int)> idInt2 = []( const int &i) {return i;};
```